# Collision quadrant in godot appears

Tags: collision-detection, tilemap, godot

I am learning to use godot following this video:
[Collisions with Autotiles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPgTlxb7Bno&list=PL9FzW-m48fn2SlrW0KoLT4n5egNdX-W9a&index=8)

The problem is that when I create the collision for the cliffs using tilemap, it appears me a blue quadrant indicating the collision. What should I do for what these "quadrants" do not appear?

[image: Game image]

As you can see, all the cliffs are blue for indicate me the collision, but I have no idea about what to do for hide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "Visible collision shapes" option from the [Debug](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/debug/overview_of_debugging_tools.html) menu:

[image]